# regex for comma seperated numeric value in jquery

Tags: jquery, regex

I am trying to use regex for comma seperated multiple numeric values in jquery. I tried the following regex.

```
/^[0-9,.]*$/
^[0-9]+(?:,[0-9]+)*$
```

Following are some validations:

```
12,12.5 - true
23,24 - true
23,abc - false
12,12.2.2.2 - should be false but returning true
```

The above regex I tried also validates 12.12.12 which should be false.
How am I to solve this? Any help/suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some expected inputs.How can somebody guess what exactly you want..........

Comment: @Uchiha it doesn't validate 12.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this.Check it out.

Regex:

```
^([0-9]+|[0-9]+.?[0-9]+){1}(,?([0-9]+|[0-9]+.?[0-9]+))*$
```

Working [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mU8qP6/2)

Comment: but it's not validating single digit as 1,9. I have to type as 01,09. Is there any way around for this too?

Comment: I will check it out give me 5mins

Comment: check out this `^([0-9]+|[0-9]+.?[0-9]+){1}(,?([0-9]+|[0-9]+.?[0-9]+))*$` .Working [Regex](https://regex101.com/r/mU8qP6/2)

Answer (score 0):

2 quick changes

- Add `.` to character class
- Move the `,` out of the character class

The regex can be

```
^[\d.]+(,[\d.]+)+$
```

[**Regex Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/yK0qL0/2)

**Example**

```
/^[\d.]+(,[\d.]+)+$/.test("2.2.2.2")
=> false

/^[\d.]+(,[\d.]+)+$/.test("2.2,2.2")
=> true
```